# Difference between := and = operators in Go

Tags: go

What is the difference between the `=` and `:=` operators, and what are the use cases for them? They both seem to be for an assignment?

Comment: **Also see this**: [Go Variables Visual Guide](https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/learn-go-lang-variables-visual-tutorial-and-ebook-9a061d29babe). I wrote an article about it.

Comment: The semantics...

Comment: If you want to use a specific type `x := uint32(123)` works for example.   It must be obvious for most people but I had to think a few minutes ;-)

Comment: I highly recommend starting with the Tour of Go: https://tour.golang.org/basics/9

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Only `=` is the *assignment operator*.

`:=` is a part of the syntax of the [*short variable declaration*](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) clause.
 There are some rules though. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654233/115363) for more details.

Comment: Looks like `:=` is listed as an operator here https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators_and_punctuation, so I'm not sure I agree that "`:=` is actually not an operator"

Answer (score 501):

In Go, `:=` is for declaration + assignment, whereas `=` is for assignment only.

For example, `var foo int = 10`  is the same as `foo := 10`.

Comment: Is there a use case for `=` as opposed to `:=`? Should you just always use `:=`?

Comment: @KennethWorden Go won't let you use ```:=``` to assign to a variable that has already been declared, unless you are assigning to multiple variables at once, and at least one of those variables is new.

Comment: the `int` is not required, `var foo = 10` is the same as `foo := 10`

Comment: @KennyWorden, yes. You can't use := outside a function.

Comment: I believe the := is used for type inference as well, you can use it like ` i := 1 ` as opposed to ` var i int = 1 `

Answer (score 327):

TLDR:

- Declare a variable, use:
  `:=`.
- Change a variable’s value, use: `=`.

*There are some rules and the TLDR is not always true.*

As others have explained already, `:=` is for both declaration, assignment, and also for redeclaration; and it guesses (*infers*) the variable's type automatically.

**For example, `foo := 32` is a short-hand form of:**

```
var foo int
foo = 32

// OR:
var foo int = 32

// OR:
var foo = 32
```

---

**/* Here are the rules: */**

**★ 1st Rule:**

You can't use `:=` outside of `funcs`. It's because, outside a func, a statement should start with a keyword.

```
// no keywords below, illegal.
illegal := 42

// `var` keyword makes this statement legal.
var legal = 42

func foo() {
  alsoLegal := 42
  // reason: it's in a func scope.
}
```

---

**★ 2nd Rule:**

You can't use them twice (*in the same scope*):

```
legal := 42
legal := 42 // <-- error
```

Because, `:=` introduces **"a new variable"**, hence using it twice does not redeclare a second variable, so it's illegal.

---

**★ 3rd Rule:**

You can use them for multi-variable declarations and assignments:

```
foo, bar   := 42, 314
jazz, bazz := 22, 7
```

---

**★ 4th Rule (Redeclaration):**

You can use them twice in **"multi-variable"** declarations, *if one of the variables is new*:

```
foo, bar  := someFunc()
foo, jazz := someFunc()  // <-- jazz is new
baz, foo  := someFunc()  // <-- baz is new
```

This is legal, because, you're not declaring all the variables, you're just reassigning new values to the existing variables, and declaring new variables at the same time. This is called *redeclaration*.

---

**★ 5th Rule:**

You can use the short declaration to declare a variable in a newer scope even if that variable is already declared with the same name before:

```
var foo int = 34

func some() {
  // because foo here is scoped to some func
  foo := 42  // <-- legal
  foo = 314  // <-- legal
}
```

Here, `foo := 42` is legal, because, it declares `foo` in `some()` func's scope. `foo = 314` is legal, because, it just assigns a new value to `foo`.

---

**★ 6th Rule:**

You can declare the same name in short statement blocks like: **if**, **for**, **switch**:

```
foo := 42
if foo := someFunc(); foo == 314 {
  // foo is scoped to 314 here
  // ...
}
// foo is still 42 here
```

Because, `foo` in `if foo := ...`, only belongs to that `if` clause and it's in a different scope.

---

**References:**

- [Short Variable Declaration Rules](https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-short-variable-declaration-rules-6df88c881ee)
- [A Visual Guide to Go Variables](https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/learn-go-lang-variables-visual-tutorial-and-ebook-9a061d29babe)

Answer (score 25):

`:=` is a short-hand for declaration.

```
a := 10
b := "gopher"
```

`a` will be declared as an `int` and initialized with value `10` where as `b` will be declared as a string and initialized with value `gopher`.

Their equivalents using `=` would be

```
var a = 10
var b = "gopher"
```

`=` is assignment operator. It is used the same way you would use it in any other language.

You can omit the type when you declare the variable and an initializer is present (http://tour.golang.org/#11).

Comment: _«= is assignment operator. It is used the same way you would use it in any other language.»_ Except in Ada where `=` is only for comparison and `:=` is for assignment...

Answer (score 19):

The := means declare **and** assign while the = means to simply assign.

Answer (score 12):

`:=` declares and assigns, `=` just assigns

It's useful when you don't want to fill up your code with type or struct declarations.

```
// Usage with =
var i int
var U, V, W float64
var k = 0
var x, y float32 = -1, -2

// Usage with :=
i, j := 0, 10
f := func() int { return 7 }
ch := make(chan int)
```

Answer (score 8):

from the reference doc : ([tour.golang.org](http://tour.golang.org/#13))

**Inside a function**, the `:=` short assignment statement can be used in place of a var declaration with implicit type.

**Outside a function**, every construct begins with a keyword (var, func, and so on) and the := construct is not available.

Answer (score 2):

In Go
`:=` is for declaration and assignment also
whereas `=` is only for the Assignment

for example:

```
var s string = "Omkar"

s:= "Omkar"
```