# Is there a way to store arithmetic results into a helm variable?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a variable say :

```
{{- $var := 7 -}}
```

I need to perform an arithmetic operation involving this variable and store the result back into the same i.e for example

```
var = var + 2
```

I tried doing :

```
{{- $var := add ( {{ $var }} 2 ) -}}
```

but doesn't seem to work, throws this error

```
unexpected "{" in parenthesized pipeline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be (see [`add`](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html) & documentation):

```
{{- $var := add $var 2 -}}
```

For example

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: myconfigmap
data:
  {{ $var := 5  }}
  prevVal: {{ $var }}
  {{ $var = add $var 2 }}
  newVal: {{ $var }}
```

Rendered:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: myconfigmap
data:
  
  prevVal: 5
  
  newVal: 7
```

`=` is to assign a variable and `:=` is define and assign a variable.

Comment: we use ":=" for redeclaration right? so in order to re-use the same "var" the next time it should be involved in an "=" operation instead of ":=" right?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my example above, := is to declare and assign a variable. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091638/5078746